# Formatting An Output File In Python

Tags: python, tkinter

My program outputs an .nc file, which is a plain text g-code file. When I call

```
        f.write(str(uniform))
```

the file is formatted as follows:

("('G20G90M3S200G1X' 0.03125 'F20G1X' 0.0625 'F15G1X' 0.09375 'F10G1X' 0.125 'F20S300

How can I fix my code so the output file is formatted as follows:

G20
G90
M3S200
G1X0.03125F20
G1X0.0625F15
G1X0.09375F10
G1X0.125F20S300

I added .replace() which removed the commas, but I don't know how to get rid of the single and double quotes or the empty spaces and I don't know how to add line breaks where I need them.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import os
os.system('clear')

root = Tk()
root.title('Pickup Coil Turn Count Calculator')

app_width = 400
app_height = 600

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

x = (screen_width / 2) - (app_width / 2)
y = (screen_height / 2) - (app_height / 2)
root.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')
root.configure(bg='light grey')

my_notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
my_notebook.pack()

my_frame1 = Frame(my_notebook, width=400, height=600, bg='light grey')
my_frame2 = Frame(my_notebook, width=400, height=600, bg='light grey')

my_frame1.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
my_frame2.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

my_notebook.add(my_frame1, text='Turn Count Calculator')
my_notebook.add(my_frame2, text='G-Code Builder')


def turn_count():
    width, length, ohms, resistance = float(e2.get()), float(e3.get()), float(options[clicked.get()]), float(e5.get())
    turn_count = resistance / ohms * 1000 * 12 / ((width * 3.14) + length + length - width * .19) * .969
    count_label['text'] = int(turn_count)


def no_scatter():
    block1 = 'G20'\
             'G90'\
             'M3S200'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .125, 'F20'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .25, 'F15'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .375, 'F10'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .5, 'F20S300'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .625, 'F10'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .75, 'F10'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .875, 'F15'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()), 'F20S600'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .875, 'F20'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .75, 'F15'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .625, 'F10'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .5, 'F10S1200'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .375, 'F10'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .25, 'F10'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .125, 'F15'\
             'G1X', '.000', 'F20'
    block2 = 'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .125, 'F20'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .25, 'F15'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .375, 'F10'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .5, 'F20'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .625, 'F10'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .75, 'F10'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .875, 'F15'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()), 'F20'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .875, 'F20'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .75, 'F15'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .625, 'F10'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .5, 'F10'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .375, 'F10'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .25, 'F10'\
             'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .125, 'F15'\
             'G1X', '.000', 'F20'
    uniform = str(block1), str(block2)
    with open('No Scatter.nc', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(uniform).replace(',', ''))


myLabel = Label(my_frame1, text='Enter Core Height', bg='light grey')
myLabel.pack(pady=10)
e1 = Entry(my_frame1, width=10, justify='center', border=0)
e1.pack()

myLabel = Label(my_frame1, text='Enter Core Width', bg='light grey')
myLabel.pack(pady=10)
e2 = Entry(my_frame1, width=10, justify='center', border=0)
e2.pack()

myLabel = Label(my_frame1, text='Enter Core Length', bg='light grey')
myLabel.pack(pady=10)
e3 = Entry(my_frame1, width=10, justify='center', border=0)
e3.pack()

myLabel = Label(my_frame1, text='Enter Target Resistance In Ohms', bg='light grey')
myLabel.pack(pady=10)
e5 = Entry(my_frame1, width=10, justify='center', border=0)
e5.pack()

myLabel = Label(my_frame1, text='Select Wire Gauge', bg='light grey')
myLabel.pack(pady=10)


options = {
    '38': '648.0',
    '39': '846.0',
    '40': '1079.0',
    '41': '1323.0',
    '42': '1659.0',
    '43': '2143.0',
    '44': '2593.0'
}

clicked = StringVar()
clicked.set(list(options.keys())[0])

drop = OptionMenu(my_frame1, clicked, *options.keys())
drop.pack()

Button(my_frame1, text='Calculate Turn Count', command=turn_count).pack(pady=30)

myLabel = Label(my_frame1, text='Turn Count', font='arial 14 bold', bg='light grey')
myLabel.pack()

count_label = Label(my_frame1, width=10, font='arial 20 bold', fg='white', bg='dark grey')
count_label.pack()

myLabel = Label(my_frame1, bg='light grey')
myLabel.pack()

myLabel = Label(my_frame2, text='Enter Winder Motor RPM', bg='light grey')
myLabel.pack(pady=10)
e6 = Entry(my_frame2, width=10, justify='center', border=0)
e6.pack()

myLabel = Label(my_frame2, bg='light grey')
myLabel.pack()

myLabel = Label(my_frame2, text='Select A Winding Pattern', bg='light grey')
myLabel.pack(pady=10)

Button(my_frame2, text='No Scatter', command=no_scatter).pack(pady=10)

Button(my_frame2, text='Minimum Scatter').pack(pady=10)

Button(my_frame2, text='Moderate Scatter').pack(pady=10)

Button(my_frame2, text='Maximum Scatter').pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Formatting is covered in any tutorial on "python output formatting".  See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's YOU that are making it one big string.  If you just create this as a list of strings, your problem becomes trivial.

```
    block1 = ['G20',
             'G90',
             'M3S200',
             'G1X'+ str(float(e1.get()) * .125)+ 'F20',
             'G1X'+ str(float(e1.get()) * .25)+ 'F15',
             'G1X'+ str(float(e1.get()) * .375, 'F10',
             'G1X'+ str(float(e1.get()) * .5)+ 'F20S300',
             'G1X'+ str(float(e1.get()) * .625)+ 'F10',
...
```

Once you have that, you can write it with `'\n'.join(block1)`.  There's no point in creating your data in a way that isn't useful for you.

Comment: This application is my first effort with Python. I started 5 days ago and ironically, the next chapter in my Python book is about lists. I would've gotten there eventually, but you helped me get there much faster. Thanks!